# search patterns on running-config with multiple queries

Tags: python, networking, standards-compliance

I am having a problem with creating a script, to search a file for certain patterns. Once the pattern is found in the file, it should print a message.
The problem I am having is that it is just executing the first for loop and not printing the next message.

```
`import r 
f = open('/R1.ios') 
V96189 = ['session-limit']
V96197 = ['logging enable']

for pattern in V96189:
    for line in f:
        if pattern in line:
            print('V-96189',    'Not a finding',    'session-limit is set')  

for pattern in V96197:
    for line in f:
        if pattern in line:
            print('V-96197',    'Not a finding',    'logging enable is set')'
`
```